# Running an long-running Python function from Django

Tags: python, django

Here's the rough workflow:

```
Request for a job comes in to a particular view -> Job entered in Database -> requestProcessor() launched independent of current process -> Response "Job has been entered" is returned instantly ->
```

`requestProcessor()` looks at the database, sees if there are any outstanding Jobs to be processed, and begins processing it. Takes ~3 hours to complete.

I've been confused by this problem for a long long time now. Should I be using `multiprocessing.Pool`'s `apply_async`? I have zero experience with multiple processes so I'm not sure what the best approach to this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this fairly easily. This is the sort of thing one might use `Celery` for (see [Iain Shelvington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27091215/1775603)). To answer your question regarding how the multiprocessing module works, though, you could also simply do something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def do_job(seconds):
    """
    This is the function that will run your three-hour job.
    """
    time.sleep(seconds)                     # just sleep to imitate a long job
    print 'done!'                           # will go to stdout, so you will see this
                                            # most easily in test on local server

def test(request):
    """
    This is your view.
    """
    # In place of this comment, check the database.
    # If job already running, return appropriate template.
    p = Process(target=do_job, args=(15,))  # sleep for 15 seconds
    p.start()                               # but do not join
    message = 'Process started.'
    return render(request, 'test.html',
                  {'message': message})
```

If you run this on your local test server, you will immediately be taken to the test page, and then in your `stdout` you will see `done!` show up 15 seconds later.

If you were to use something like this, you would also need to think about whether or not you will need to notify the user when the job finishes. In addition, you would need to think about whether or not to block further job requests until the first job is done. I don't think you'll want users to be able to start 500 processes haphazardly! You should check your database processes to see if the job is already running.

Comment: What's the difference between this and the `pool = Pool(processes=1); result = pool.apply_async(myfunction)` method? Considering I'm calling a python function itself this seems a bit more convenient.

Comment: @user1265125 `Pool` is for a pool of worker processes. I believe you only require one process here. Is that correct? Your description suggests that this may be an administrative-type job. The method in my answer also calls a python function (which I have arbitrarily named `do_job`).

Comment: This will cause uncontrollable growth of processes to happen, if the view is called quite often.

Comment: @kroolik Yes, I agree. I mentioned this in my last paragraph. Consideration needs to be given to this fact.

Answer (score 3):

[Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) is a great tool for implementing this exact type of functionality. You can use it a "task queue", for example:

tasks.py

```
from celery import task

@task
def do_job(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    This is the function that does a "job"
    """
    # TODO: Long running task here
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from .tasks import do_job

def view(request):
    """
    This is your view.
    """
    do_job.delay(*args, **kwargs)
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'message': 'Job has been entered'})
```

Calling [.delay](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay) will register do_job for execution by one of your celery workers but will not block execution of the view. A task is not executed until a worker becomes free, so you should not have any issues with the number of processes spawned by this approach.

Comment: I would suggest adding versions for both django and celery. Update the code can be helpful.